# using .size() member function on a vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm having some confusion with the usage of the .size() member function of vector.

So what I have is an object that displays a series of bitmaps in sequence, these bitmaps are stored as pointers in a vector. This vector is then passed by reference "&" in the construction of my "animation" object, which does all the work cycling through the bitmaps.

Everything works as I expected except that calling .size() on my referenced vector of bitmap pointers, which does not return anything, though I know the vector has contents.

This then causes the animation to cycle through normally, then it trips up because its trying to access an element that is out of bounds, due to .size() returning nothing, messing up my bounds checking.

My only guess is that my syntax is not correct, or that i'm not properly understanding the usage.

```
#include "animation.h"
#include "helperFunctions.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

animation::animation(int x, int y, SDL_Renderer* screenRenderer, std::vector<SDL_Texture*>& sprites) {
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _sprites = &sprites;
    _frames =  sprites.size() - 1;///this is to be used as an indexer, eg. 0 frames is 1 in reality, 3 is 4...
    _currentFrame = 0;///first frame index
    mainScreen = screenRenderer;
    _finished = false;
}

animation::animation(const animation& orig) {

}

animation::~animation() {
    std::cout << "animation object deleted!" << std::endl;
}

void animation::cycleFrame() {
    applyTexture(_x, _y, (*_sprites)[_currentFrame], mainScreen);
    std::cout << "_currentFrame: " << _currentFrame << std::endl;
    std::cout << "_frames      : " << _frames << std::endl;
    _currentFrame++;
    if (_currentFrame == _frames) {
        _finished = true;
    }
}
```

Also I should add that i'm not asking for help with anything SDL, just the whole vector.size() thing.

Thank in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

So I did some digging and it seems like .size() is also returning as 0 on the vector before it is even being passed to the constructor...
in main() I have:

```
std::vector<SDL_Texture*> explosion16;        
explosion16.reserve(16);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    explosion16[i] = loadTexture(loadImage("gfx/explosions/explosion_16/e" + to_string(i) + ".bmp"));
}
cout << "explosion16.size() : " << explosion16.size() << endl;/////this returns as zero, 0
```

Comment: "....which does not return anything..." i guess you meant "..which returns zero..."

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code presented. Bare in mind that `sprites.size()` is calculated at the time the `animation` object is created. It is not a "live" size of the `sprites`. If you require a "live" size, then capture a pointer or reference to the `sprites` vector and use that for the size calculation

Comment: the code you posted looks fine. Maybe you can also post the part, where you check the bound / where the out of bound occurs

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys,
the bounds checking is done by the if statement in the cycleFrame() method, that checks to see if the elapsed frames is equivalent to the total amount of frames, if so then finished is set to true.
Externally there is a function that controls the deletion and creation of animation objects depending on the finished flag

Comment: also, if I just manually hard code _frames to 16 then everything works perfect.

Comment: are you sure that your animation needs a pointer to the `sprites` vector? Why not just make the animation "own" the sprites (i.e. pass `sprites` in the constr and just `this->sprites = sprites`). I still guess, your problem arises because you store the size of the vector and then add/remove sprites from it without updating `_frames`.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ please

Comment: Your code looks fine in regards to passing in `sprites` to the constructor.
What looks fishy is the empty copy constructor you have (if the implementation is not only omitted for brevity)
For example, now if you create an `animation`, pass it to a method by value and call `cycleFrame` on that copy, the members, including `_frames` will be uninitialized

Comment: aaah yes, sorry about that, I never intend to use that copy constructor, the IDE creates that automatically.

Comment: Okay ive just found something more, out in main(), im doing some debug on the vector that is passed to the animation construction.
What ive found is that .size() isnt working there either.
So what I have is:
    `std::vector<SDL_Texture*> explosion16;
    explosion16.reserve(16);//gfx/explosions/explosion_16/e0.bmp
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        explosion16[i] = loadTexture(loadImage("gfx/explosions/explosion_16/e" + to_string(i) + ".bmp"));
    }
    cout << "explosion16.size() : " << explosion16.size() << endl;`

Comment: sorry, im really not used to this kind of forum commenting ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment:
If you use `reserve()`, that does not increment the size, only the capacity.
You should either use `resize()`, and than you can use the indexer to initialize the members, or keep `reserve` and use `push_back()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: yesssss, that got it, thanks for that.
So what I have learnt from this is that there is a lot more to the size value of a vector than meets the eye...
Ill keep this in mind.
Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

in below line :

```
_frames =  sprites.size() - 1;
```

_frames might be -1 in case sprites.size() is zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(sprites.size() > 0)
 _frames =  sprites.size() - 1;
```

Comment: An explanation of what this does / why you need to do it will make this a better answer.